# snmpget for HP switch - ifType not found

Tags: snmp, hp, linux, monitoring, snmpv3

I'm learning about fetching information via `SNMP` towards our HP switches. I'm trying to query a switch using the OID `BRIDGE-MIB::dot1dTpFdbPort` included with a known MAC address `50:65:f3:2e:c5:5c`, as such `.1.3.6.1.2.1.17.4.3.1.2.80.101.243.46.197.92`.

```
$ snmpget -v3 -Oe my_switch .1.3.6.1.2.1.17.4.3.1.2.80.101.243.46.197.92
BRIDGE-MIB::dot1dTpFdbPort.'Pe...\' = INTEGER: 31466
```

It returns the integer `31466`. I'm then trying to query the same switch using the OID `IF-MIB::ifType` included with the integer `31466`, as such `.1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.3.31466`.

```
$ snmpget -v3 -Oe my_switch .1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.3.31466
IF-MIB::ifType.31466 = No Such Instance currently exists at this OID
```

Why can't the port with the integer `31466` be found on the switch? Am I missing something? I appreciate any help as I'm quite new to the `SNMP` and OID stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are missing a lookup in dot1dBasePortTable to convert from a dot1dBasePort to a dot1dBasePortIfIndex.

Comment: Thank you. I was indeed missing looking up the index of the port using `dot1dBasePortIfIndex`. `/usr/bin/snmpbulkwalk -v3 -Oe my_switch .1.3.6.1.2.1.17.1.4.1.2 | grep 31466` returns INTEGER `31659` and `/usr/bin/snmpget -v3 -Oe my_switch .1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.3.31659` now returns INTEGER `161` (in my case).